# SQL Server Average Query

Tags: sql-server, average

Can somebody help me about how to query the average of this?

I have this table.

```
 teacher | class | students | rating
 -----------------------------------
   T1        1      001        6
   T1        1      002        6
   T1        2      003        1
   T1        3      004        1
   T2        1      001        6
   T2        1      002        6
   T2        2      003        1
   T2        3      004        1
```

if I do `Select teacher, class, avg(rating) from table group by teacher, class` then I get this:

```
teacher | class | rating
------------------------
   T1       1     6
   T1       2     1
   T1       3     1
   T2       1     6
   T2       2     1
   T2       3     1
```

what I want to do is get the average `rating` of that result and group it by `teacher` which is:

```
teacher | rating
------------------------
   T1      2.66667
   T2      2.66667
```

because if i do `Select avg(rating) from table group by teacher`, I get

```
teacher | rating
------------------------
   T1      3.5
   T2      3.5
```

Comment: I have given the answer to same question some hours ago and then question got deleted ? Why ?

Comment: Average of average is generally not a valid measurement

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
SELECT teacher,avg(avgrating) as avgrating
FROM
(Select teacher, class, avg(rating) avgrating
from TableName 
group by teacher, class) Temp
GROUP BY teacher
```

Result:

```
TEACHER   AVGRATING
T1        2.666666
T2        2.666666
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9fd1e/1).

**OR:**

```
SELECT T1.teacher,avg(T2.avgrating) as rating
FROM TableName T1 JOIN
(SELECT teacher,class,avg(rating) as avgrating
 FROM TableName T2
 GROUP BY teacher,class) T2 ON T1.teacher=T2.teacher
GROUP BY T1.teacher
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9fd1e/8).

Comment: I actually thought about that. I'm just wondering is there another way instead of using nested select

Comment: @akoxi: I have edited my answer with another solution using join. Both are same basically. You will have to use an inner query to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

use a nested select:

```
select teacher , avg(avgr) from
 (Select teacher, class, avg(rating) avgr from table group by teacher, class) qry
group by teacher
```